# "insufficient memory for Java Runtime Environment to continue" in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-8

I am trying to run `java -Xmx5g -cp stanford-corenlp-3.8.0.jar:stanford-corenlp-models-3.8.0.jar:* edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,mention,coref -coref.algorithm neural -file example_file.txt` to find mentions of the same entity in a text. 
But when I run that command in terminal, the process was killed and the error is written in a log, saying that insufficient memory for Java Runtime Environment to continue.

I am using Ubuntu with:

> java version "1.8.0_151".
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
>
> Java Hotspot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)

As the log is quite long and the question body cannot fit all the log's details.

Here is the log: [error log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hr159haud1zacvb/hs_err_pid3330.log?dl=0)

[Update] I have increase the physical memory of my virtual machine. Now I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:649)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.SentenceUtils.listToString(SentenceUtils.java:186)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.SentenceUtils.listToString(SentenceUtils.java:169)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.SentenceUtils.listToString(SentenceUtils.java:148)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ParserAnnotator.doOneSentence(ParserAnnotator.java:360)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ParserAnnotator.doOneSentence(ParserAnnotator.java:254)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.SentenceAnnotator.annotate(SentenceAnnotator.java:102)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotationPipeline.annotate(AnnotationPipeline.java:76)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.annotate(StanfordCoreNLP.java:599)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.annotate(StanfordCoreNLP.java:609)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$$Lambda$55/45416784.accept(Unknown Source)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.processFiles(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1172)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.processFiles(StanfordCoreNLP.java:945)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.run(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1274)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.main(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1345)
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: `-Xmx` is heap, but from the logs it seems that your application is trying to allocate memory off-heap (`mmap` error)

Comment: also could be this... https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187709

Comment: @Eugene meaning the command I replace `java -Xmx5g` with `java -XX:-UseCompressedOops` and run it?

Comment: well no, if it's that bug that you are hitting, you should keep your `-Xmx` and simply disable compressed oops via `-XX:-UseCompressedOop`. but that comes at a performance cost - you should understand the implications of this

Answer (score 2):

The error report says this:

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 335785984 bytes 
  for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
```

Taking this at face value:

- The first explanation means that the operating system has refused a request from the JVM to allocate a large chunk of native memory **because** the resources (physical memory or swap space) are not available.
- You are using a 64bit JVM so the second possible explanation is not applicable.

The first explanation is plausible.  Possible fixes might be:

- add more physical memory; e.g. get a bigger machine or virtual machine
- add more swap space
- reduce max heapsize specified via the -Xmx parameter

Comment: i tried adding more physical memory and an error occurred. I have updated my question with the new error

Comment: i also tried to reduce the max heapsize and having the same newly updated error

Comment: I tried all three fixes, but all the error occurred is the newly updated error in my question

Comment: So how much physical memory and swap space do you have now?

Comment: I have 4.45 gb for mem and 1gb for swap

Comment: You need at least as much swap space as the **total** virtual memory utilization of your processes.

Comment: now my swap has 5.6gb, I tried running the command again. the same error occurs

Comment: Make it 10Gb swap space.  Also make sure that you don't have a ulimit set on your virtual memory size.

Comment: how can i check for ulimit?

Comment: the error still persists with 10gb swap space and no ulimit was set on my virtual mem

Comment: The problem now could be regular heap space.  Are you trying to process a huge amount of text ... or something?  Is the "problem" you are tying to solve simply too big?

Comment: I think there are a huge amount of text. Here’s the text: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a6v96hrlwfhront/SMRT_lightningstrike_9articles.txt?dl=0

Comment: do i need to increase the -Xmx?

Comment: You could try that.  But it is not clear that it will work.  It could be that the problem is simply too big.  And it is also conceivable that there are ways to get that application to use less memory.